# SAS issue: Need Outputs for age_groups when count = 0

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get SAS to give me all the age_groups when count = 0. I can't figure it out and if I have to copy and paste 2000 lines from one xlsx to another, I will mess up counts somewhere as there are rows missing for age_groups. I tried various ways to make it work, including the use of sparse in the PROC FREQ step. None of them seem to work and I think it's because the age_group is a character value so it's completely missing from the frequency counts.

Here is what currently outputs:
[image: what I get]

Here's what I need: [image: what I need]

Here is the SAS Code I used for this output:

```
PROC FREQ data=partial ORDER=INTERNAL ;
    tables mmwr_case*age_group / out=partial_2021 sparse list nocol nocum norow nopercent;
    by mmwr_case;
    where case_year = 2021; 
    title 'Cases, 2021, by MMWR Week';
RUN;
```

Comment: You need to use a format and Completetypes in this case with PROC TABULATE instead of FREQ. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/239-2011.pdf

Comment: Basically if it's nowhere in the data you somehow have to tell SAS that it's a category that exists and to have it match your displayed output it looks like you need a format anyways.

Comment: I'm also assuming those are examples otherwise, why does 12-17 for 202140 show 49 in one table but 0 in another?

Comment: How is the value for 'age_group' assigned?  Is there a master list of valid `age_groups`?   Is age computed as decimal years (seeing how you have 0.5)

Comment: Thank you. this worked out! I ended up creating two tables for year_week and age_group and then merging those tables back with the original file and it provided all zero counts.